# Get Unique rows in SELECT query using JPA in POSTGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, locking, spring-batch

I am working in a Spring batch application in Spring boot which will be running in two different instances, where I have a scenario in which I have to retrieve unique rows from a table. By unique I mean, one row per instance. For example,
 
id       language
1        java
2        python

if I have two rows and when I call a `SELECT` query with limit one, For first instance I should get id 1 and for second instance id 2 should be returned. So far I have tried using JPA Lock `@Lock(value = LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)` This doesn't work. Each time I get the same row. I have also tried using `JdbcTemplate` with `SELECT * FROM some_table LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED`. This is also not working. My postgres version is 10.3 . Is there a way to achieve this.

Number of instances of my application might grow in the future. So I want to handle this as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why should the exact same query return different rows? This would be quite strange, wouldn't it? Why don't you just execute one query, without limit 1, and iterate through the results? Or at least sort by ID, and change the offset for each query?

Comment: What I have mentioned is just a sample. Actual logic will be different. Actually, it will be run from two different machines. Each instance of the application should process a unique row.

Comment: Then ask about what you really want to achieve.

Comment: You'll need to find a way to coordinate the jobs. Start by getting the number of rows, and assign a slice to each batch, or handle the even rows in one instance, and the odd ones in the second, or whatever.

Comment: select * from language where id % 2 = 0: returns the rows with an even id.

Answer (score 0):

You want each instance to process a different partition of your table. In this case, I would recommend using a partitioned step.

For example, you can partition the table by even/odd IDs, and make each instance process a partition. This is IMO better than locking the table and using `LIMIT 1` to force each instance read one row (This won't work as you mentioned and even if it works, it would be very poor in terms of performance).

You can find a sample job of how to partition a table here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/partitionJdbcJob.xml along with the corresponding partitioner here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/common/ColumnRangePartitioner.java

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My application instances might grow in the future. I would like to handle that scenario as well.